# Submiting jobs with --conf not working

Tags: apache-spark

I've tried to add **jmx** to my **spark executors** with "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions". I've put `--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=\"my Options\""` in my sumbit file, started job, verified if this configuration is visible on webUI. Then I have verified **jmx** with **netstat -an** and there was no listening on port I have specified. Then I have put same options in **spark-defaults.conf** and everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried `--conf "\"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=my Options\""` with same effect.

Comment: You can try
.setConf() method on spark context in the code  and check whether its taking the configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried everything but a simplest solution:

`--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=my Options"`

Now everything works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try \\ instead of \ it might work.
Also check if setting configurations using .setConf() method on spark context in the code solves the problem.